# Netlogo list member? why not working

Tags: list, netlogo, member

I have a problem with a NetLogo-list (V. 6.0.2) and the member? command, somehow not doing what I want it to do.

Each turtle builds its list "aware-of-who":

```
ask turtles [
    foreach cheater-list [ x ->
          if random-float 100 < 90
            [set aware-of-who lput ([who] of x ) aware-of-who]
    ]
```

It builds the lists of who-numbers successfully for the turtles.

Then I ask turtles to look for those neighbors, that have their who-number in their "aware-of-who" list (i.a. are "aware of them"), with this code:

```
let punishers  (turtles-on neighbors) with 
    [ member? ([who] of myself) ( [aware-of-who] of self) = true]
```

It does not seem to report true, even if from all I can tell it should (the respective who numbers do appear in their lists). The code also does report true if I ask for `(turtles-on neighbors) with [ empty? aware-of-who = false]`.

Any ideas what's wrong here?
Thanx!!

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a case of mixing up `self` and `myself`. In the following code:

```
let punishers  (turtles-on neighbors) with 
  [ member? ([who] of myself) ( [aware-of-who] of self) = true]
```

The code between the square brackets is passed to the `with` reporter and runs in the context of the calling turtle's neighbors. So within the reporter, `self` is the neighbor and `myself` is the calling turtle. You have it the other way around.

That being said... *don't do it this way*! And by this, I mean: *don't use lists of `who` numbers*. It is almost never necessary to use `who` numbers in NetLogo. Whenever you think you need `who` numbers for something, come ask a question here: someone will most likely show you a better way to do it.

The way around `who` numbers is usually to store references to turtles directly, either in a list or an agentset. It seems like you already know how that works, since `cheater-list` is apparently a list of turtles.

To construct you list of cheaters that a turtle is aware of, you could just use [`filter`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter):

```
let known-cheaters filter [ random-float 100 < 90 ] cheaters
```

Finding your punishers then becomes a bit nicer:

```
let punishers (turtles-on neighbors) with [
  member? self [ known-cheaters ] of myself
]
```

Also note that you should almost never write `= true` or `= false`. If something is true or false, you can use it directly in an expression (with a `not` in front if you're interested in the case where it's false). For example, you can write:

```
turtles with [ not member? self cheaters ]
```

instead of:

```
turtles with [ member? self cheaters = false ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Turns out that the actual problem was that I DIDN'T in fact build a list of turtles, but a list with a turtle agent-set as an item. I got it to work now with `let cheaters  (turtles-on neighbors) with [harvestPref = "high"]
     set aware-of-who n-of  ( 0.9 * count cheaters) cheaters ` However, I think the self / myself codes are the way I had put them: `let punishers  (turtles-on neighbors) with [ member? myself [aware-of-who] of self]` It does work this way but not if I switch up the self/myself commands. That also is congruent with the example in the NL manual

Comment: The code you have gives you the neighbors that have the central turtle in their `aware-of-who` agentset. I thought you wanted the neighbors who were in the `aware-of-who` agentset of the central turtle, but it seems like I misinterpreted your intent. I'm glad your code is working... and that you moved away from `who` numbers! :-)